# Filter objects with empty generic content

Tags: django

My notification model is generic, meaning it can hold any object. It looks like this:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='notifications')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_notifications', blank=True, null=True)

    object_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    object = GenericForeignKey('object_type', 'object_id')

    type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=config.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_OPTIONS)
    unread = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=False, default='notification')

    # Other
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
```

Whenever a user deletes an object that a notification relates to, it ends up pointing to a NoneType object instead. I want to filter out Notifications that don't relate to anything to the user.

I've already tried:

```
Notification.objects.exclude(object=None)
```

and

```
Notification.objects.filter(object=None)
```

However both gives me an error that I cannot do a reverse relationship query on generic content type objects. How do I filter or get all Notifications that are pointing to non-existing objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found, it is not possible to use the generic foreign key in `filter()`. However, as all you want to do is exclude objects without a related object, you can filter on `object_id` instead.

```
Notification.objects.filter(object_id__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work because the id has already been assigned. The content type and id is assigned, but the object in question is deleted.

Comment: If you define a [`GenericRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation) on the models that your generic foreign key typically points to, then notifications will be deleted when the related object is deleted. If you don't do this, Django doesn't provide an easy way to filter notifications where the related object does not exist. That would require a join to every related model, and an extra query to find out what those related models are.

Comment: There we go! Please add that to the answer so I can accept it.